# JAX-WS clinet web application - displaying the SOAP request and response in JSP

Tags: jsp, struts

I've implemented a JAX-WS client web application with a message handler where I can get the request and response. i.e.; I got the SOAP request and response as strings. I would like to get these strings and display them on every page. I'm invoking the service in the action class (struts) and forwarding the request to JSP to print the parsed data coming from the service.

Question here is - how to get these two strings to the action class back? I've sued the request scope at server side to do the same but the request is coming blank in case of client.

Any ideas?

Comment: changed tags. This is more of a Struts question than a SOAP/JAX-WS question.

Comment: Is this still an outstanding issue for you?  It looks rather old so I'm assuming that you ended up solving this...

Comment: can u provide some sample code?